# period-2 orbit for a discrete time dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems

I have the following map defined on the unit square $0\leq x,y \leq 1$:
$$B(x,y)=\begin{cases}(2x,y/3) & 
0\leq x< 1/2\\
\\(2x-1,(2+y)/3)& 1/2\leq x < 1
\end{cases}$$

How do I find two points in this unit square which form a period-2 orbit of $B$?

Comment: Why do you think that there *is* a period-2 orbit for $B$?

Comment: I never said I did. That's what I want to check and I'm unsure how. Do I just check for points $(x,y)$ where operating the map twice gives them back?

Comment: @FlyGuy Yes, you do. Just also note that fixed points (solutions of $f(z) = z$) are also solutions of $f(f(z)) = z$ and you should exclude them.

Comment: Hmmm...asking how to find something generally suggests to me that you think the thing is there to be found. Perhaps you meant to ask "How do I determine whether there's a period-2 orbit, and if there is one, how do I find it?"

Comment: @JohnHughes To be precise, it is stated in the following way in the question "Find points $y_1=(y_{11},y_{12})$ and $y_2=(y_{21},y_{22})$ which form a period-2 orbit of $B$, $y_j=y_{2n+j}$ with $n$ integer. Is this periodic orbit stable?". So suppose there do exist two points which are a period-2 orbit.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. This is just an exercise of some sort. Typically, if you want help with such things, it's a good idea to include the ideas you've had and the things you've tried in the question itself, so that we don't just think you're trying to have us do your homework for you.

Comment: @JohnHughes I understand. My apologies. I'm trying right now by simply checking for $B^2(x^\prime,y^\prime)=(x^\prime,y^\prime)$. I'll update on that matter. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I think I found them. The points are: $y_1=(1/3,3/4)$ and $y_2=(2/3,1/4)$. Clearly, I also got the two fixed points in the process.

Comment: Two questions if I may: (1) The way the question is worded is kind of bothering me. Why is it stated in the question that $y_{2n+j}=y_j$? Doesn't that make it looking for a  period-$2n$ orbit? Or now that I found the "fundamental" period-2 orbit, then all of its multiples are periodic as well? If so, why? $(2)$ Assuming my period-2 points are right, is it weird that the sum of each of the $x$ values and $y$ values equal to 1? What does that mean?

Comment: I think that it means "$y_{i} = y_{i + 2n}$ for every integer $n$." Written less formally, it means that $y_0 = y_2 = y_4 = \ldots$ and $y_1 = y_3 = y_5 = \ldots$, i.e., it's just a restatement of the idea that this is an order with a period that's either $1$ or $2$. (Presumably the fact that it's not $1$ is meant to be covered by asking you to find **two** points that constitute a period-2 orbit. As for the second question: mere coincidence. You could easily restructure the problem so that this is not true.

Comment: Thanks John. Lastly, I'd like to ask how do I check the stability of a periodic orbit in a discrete system?